# Is there a more efficient way to create weights in R?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, weighted-average, weighting

I am trying to create weights for an analysis based on the number of distinct combinations of variable values in a dataset. I tried using the `distinct()` and `count()` functions but the order of the rows is disrupted (same with using `rle()`.   The function below calculates the weights accurately and in the correct order but it is not very efficient. Is there a way to make it faster? Thanks!

```
weights<-function(v){
  sum(X==v)
}

w<-sapply(unique(X, weights)
```

Comment: perhaps using `table(x)[unique(x)]`?

Comment: You can try `tabulate(factor(X, levels = unique(X)))`.

Comment: "based on the number of distinct combinations of variable values" <-- can you provide example data and expected output?  that sounds like more than just weighting unique factor levels.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).